# Use of undeclared identifier in C++ with templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The following code cannot compile - use of undeclared identifier. I use GCC and XCode for compilation.

Everything is in a single header file.

```
include "MyArray.h"

template <typename T>
class MyBase {
public:
  MyBase();
  virtual ~MyBase();
  void addStuff(T* someStuff);
protected:
  MyArray<T*> stuff;
};

template <typename T>
MyBase<T>::MyBase() {}
template <typename T>
MyBase<T>::~MyBase() {}

template <typename T>
void MyBase<T>::addStuff(T* someStuff) {
  stuff.add(someStuff);
}

// ---------------------

template <typename T>
class MyDerived : public MyBase<T> {
public:
  MyDerived();
  virtual ~MyDerived();
  virtual void doSomething();
};

template <typename T>
MyDerived<T>::MyDerived() {}
template <typename T>
MyDerived<T>::~MyDerived() {}

template <typename T>
void MyDerived<T>::doSomething() {
  T* thingy = new T();
  addStuff(thingy); //here's the compile error. addStuff is not declared.
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jua you definitely need to lookup the cursed dependent base lookup rules regarding unqualified names. what you say is incorrect. a conforming compiler will require it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try

```
this->addStuff(thingy);
```

Comment: @juanchopanza: actually, this is right, because the compiler doesn't _know_ that it's dependent.

Comment: @moo it certainly *is* dependent and *will* be looked up at instantiation.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb thanks, I will have to do some reading. I have managed to convince myself that it is right *and* that it is wrong.

Comment: That's so bizarre to me! I just got bit as well. Do you have a link to some doc/article explaining why that is?

Comment: @GiovanniBotta I actually found a better duplicate, with better answers. See link under the question title.

Answer (score 7):

It's due to template inheritance. In such case you should mannualy specify using for base methods:

```
template <typename T>
MyDerived<T>::doSomething() {
  using MyBase<T>::addStuff;
  T* thingy = new T();
  addStuff(thingy); 
}
```

or do it by this pointer:

```
template <typename T>
MyDerived<T>::doSomething() {
  T* thingy = new T();
  this->addStuff(thingy); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues:

1. Missing semicolons after class definitions.
2. Missing type for `doSomething` method declaration/definition.
3. Missing type for definition of `addStuff` method.

After fixing that [it seems to work](http://ideone.com/X5t4R).

**Edit:** As you have fixed the syntax errors and it still does not work. As others have suggested your compiler may require you to call the `addStuff` method with `this->` prefix:

```
this->addStuff(thingy);
```

Comment: I think, that should not work as the Standard. `this->` part is a requirement here.

Comment: @Nawaz: MSVC2010 works too. Can you post a citation from standard why it should not work?

Comment: @Nawaz: No, that's not a requirement in this case. See my comment to your answer for details.

Comment: @JurajBlaho: Actually, `addStuff` is indeed a dependent name, but `this->` is not needed, as the compiler gets that hint from the *type* of the argument. I'm going to quote Mike's comment on my answer (as I will delete it soon) : *`addStuff(thingy)` is a dependent expression (since the type of thingy depends on T), and so name lookup doesn't happen until the template is instantiated. At that point, the type of the base class is known, and so `MyBase<T>::addStuff` is considered. Thus there is no need to add this in this case.*

Comment: @JurajBlaho: If you want to know more about two-phase name lookup, then see this : [The Dreaded Two-Phase Name Lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html)

Comment: @JurajBlaho I agree with Mike Seymour and Nawaz, no `this->` needed. I can't remove my answer now because it is accepted, for whatever reason.

Comment: @mike you are wrong. the this-> prefix is required. that the name is dependent is not sufficient for it to be looked up in the dependent base class. gcc fixed this bug in their latest release.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yes, you're right (the relevent bit of the standard is C++11 14.6.2/3, if anyone's interested). I should probably stop pretending that I understand the name lookup rules.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: But who does understand it, when at least two major compiler vendors did it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

use this pointer to invoke the addStuff method i.e

```
this->addStuff(thingy);
```